# амазон anguar2 cli + nginx deploy

Tags: nginx, angular2, настройка

Добрый день. Как настроить nginx, что бы завёлся проект на agular2?

Есть сервер на амазоне на нем установлен npm, http-server и nginx.
Пытался настроить по [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612339/how-can-i-deploy-my-angular-2-typescript-webpack-app).

Но не получилось. ошибка 403 Forbidden.

Конфиг nginx (тут уже пытался сделать через прокси):

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /var/www/html;
index index.html index.htm;

server_name ec2-35-156-242-165.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
    proxy_pass         http://172.31.17.51:8080;    

}
}
```

хочу заметить что когда при таких настройках делаю `http-server ./dist` 
и перехожу по ссылке домена http://***.amazonaws.com/, то никаких ошибок не выводит, но и ангуляр приложение не запускает

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55662/discussion-on-question-by----anguar2-cli-nginx-deploy).